# HSQLDB how to have multiple in memory databases

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

For instance, for each unit test I'd like to have a "different" database to use, but within the same JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that the "first time" you create an HSQL in-memory database, that becomes the "canonical" password:

```
String DB_CONNECTION_STR = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:MySpecialTestDb"; 
String DB_USERNAME_STR = "sa";
String DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD = "";
DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION_STR, DB_USERNAME_STR, DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD);
```

after this point, if you create a new connection to jdbc:hsqldb:mem:MySpecialTestDb it will connect to the same DB (and you'll need that same username and password unless you've run some privilege granting within it).  So to create a second DB, just specify a different name, and/or password:

```
String DB_CONNECTION_STR = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:AnotherTestDb"; 
String DB_USERNAME_STR = "sa"; // could use different here, doesn't matter
String DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD = "";
DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION_STR, DB_USERNAME_STR, DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD);
```

and it will effectively create a new in memory database for you.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544323/32453