# How to empty Table with HSQLDB?

Tags: java, hsqldb

I wrote these lines of java code to empty my application tables, but 
after the execution nothing happens.

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:ordini", "root", "root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
if(ORDINI) stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM ordini");
if(ORDINI_HISTORY) stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM ordini_history");
if(PRODOTTI) stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM prodotti");
```

I've already tried with TRUNCATE TABLE statement but is the same thing.

Comment: Do you commit your connection? Or is autocommit set to true?

Comment: No I didn't set the auto-commit connection property, but i tried to execute "con.commit()" at the end of the code... but the tables are still not empty.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at a file different from the file used by the code, or maybe all three flags are false. Try debugging your code, and using an absolute file path instead of a relative one.

Comment: seems like your if condition gives false. ;) kindly place full code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your program exits immediately after exectuting the statements. It should work if you add this line to the end:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("SHUTDOWN");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `executeUpdate("TRUNCATE SCHEMA public AND COMMIT")` as answered here:  [How can I wipe data from my HSQLDB after every test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990410/how-can-i-wipe-data-from-my-hsqldb-after-every-test/4991969#4991969)