# How to prevent HSQLDB from persisting data between applications runs when using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb

I am run a Spring Boot/Web application and I am using an embedded HSQLDB during prototyping. As part of this I **do not** want to persist data between runs. I would like the only data in the system to be that from those scripts.

How can I modify my configuration to achieve that?

```
@Configuration
public class RepoConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:table.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:data.sql")
                .build()
            ;
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

I tried adding a script to drop the tables before creating them, like

> DROP TABLE mytablename ;

but I kept getting the error:

> user lacks privilege or object not found: MYTABLENAME

---

PS:

- Spring Boot 2.5.0
- HSQLDB 2.6.0

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990410/how-can-i-wipe-data-from-my-hsqldb-after-every-test

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the following configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

You can find more detail on [Initialize a Database Using Hibernate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate)

Or also you can set this property `spring.datasource.data`

```
spring.datasource.data=drop.sql,data.sql
```

then those files should be in

```
src/main/resources/drop.sql
src/main/resources/data.sql
```

Comment: Okay, but if I'm not using Hibernate? Like raw JDBC for example or iBatis

Comment: Sure, you can do by another way, let me update this answer

Comment: @Sled I updated my answer, I hop this helps you.